# Automatically generate unit test for all classes derived from a particular base class

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

G++4.8.2, gtest.

We are developing a code library (used internally) of classes which derive from a common base class, `BasicGizmo`.

Today each class derived from `BasicGizmo` is required to have an `enum` member named `Size`, which has the expected size of the class.  For example:

```
#pragma (pack 1)
class SpecialGizmo
:
  BasicGizmo
{
public:
  enum {Size = 4};
  uint32_t mSomethingInteresting;
};

class SuperGizmo
:
  BasicGizmo
{
public:
  enum {Size=8};
  uint64_t mKewlData;
};
```

Elsewhere we are using gtest to construct unit tests to ensure that the actual `sizeof` these classes is what we are expecting them to be according to the `Size` enumeration:

CHECK_EQUAL (sizeof (SpecialGizmo), SpecialGizmo::Size);
  CHECK_EQUAL (sizeof (SuperGizmo), SuperGizmo::Size);

This all works as expected, except that the requirement that each of these derived classes both has a `Size` enum and that there's a unit test to check it is only enforced through code reviews.  I would rather have the compiler catch omissions before the code is ever even committed.  To do so, I would need to have a way to automatically generate the unit tests for every class that is derived from `BasicGizmo`.

Is any such mechanism possible?

Comment: yes, it is called "copy&paste"

Comment: This is not portable even between different flag settings of the same compiler. Changing compiler settings, upgrading the compiler or compiling on a different platform could all break this test.

Comment: @BЈовић:  If the programmer forgets to copy/paste then there will be no unit test and nobody will know if it's missed in a code review.  That's the whole point.  I'm looking for a way to ensure it's not missed.

Comment: @Galik:  That's not a bad thing.  On the contraty, it's one of the things the unit tests are intended to flag.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

```cpp
template<typename tp_DerivedFromGizmo> struct
t_SizeEnumMemberChecker
{
    // you can also check that tp_DerivedFromGizmo really derives from BasicGizmo
    static const bool result = (sizeof(tp_DerivedFromGizmo) == tp_DerivedFromGizmo::Size);
};

static_assert(t_SizeEnumMemberChecker<SpecialGizmo>::result, "");
```

Comment: Ok, that may be the case, but the real question is about how to automatically generate the test -- be that test a unt test or a static_asserrt.

Answer (score 1):

Your scheme could break on different platforms or different compiler settings.

If I was going to do something like this I would consider generating the test code for a given platform. You could add all the class names to a file (a `std::stringstream` in my example) and generate a testing program that outputs a *reference information file* on the size of each class/struct.

I would also consider engineering a way to include the platform and compiler settings at the beginning of the output *reference information file*.

If you make an *official* change to a class then you need to regenerate the test program to update the *reference information file*.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// These could be listed in a file
// opened with std::ifstream
std::istringstream iss
{
    "ClassA\n"
    "ClassB\n"
    "ClassC\n"
    "ClassD\n"
    "ClassE\n"
};

int main()
{
    // output an #include containing all the
    // headers you want to test
    std::cout << "#include \"all-classes.h\"" << '\n';

    // needed for generated code
    std::cout << "#include <iostream>\"" << '\n';

    // output testing code
    std::cout << "\nint main()\n{" << '\n';

    std::string class_name;
    while(std::getline(iss, class_name))
    {
        std::cout << "\tstd::cout << \"" + class_name + ": \" <<  sizeof(\"" + class_name + "\") << '\\n';" << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "}" << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
#include "all-classes.h"
#include <iostream>"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "ClassA: " <<  sizeof("ClassA") << '\n';
    std::cout << "ClassB: " <<  sizeof("ClassB") << '\n';
    std::cout << "ClassC: " <<  sizeof("ClassC") << '\n';
    std::cout << "ClassD: " <<  sizeof("ClassD") << '\n';
    std::cout << "ClassE: " <<  sizeof("ClassE") << '\n';
}
```

Then compile the output and you have your test program.

Comment: So basically, use an autogeneration tool?